# Using ASP.net Users and roles table for multiple databases or solutions... is it possible? if yes how?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Okay, So I want to basically use a single sign on...I read about it, but I cant seem to find good documentation or tutorials on how to implement it for MVC asp.net 4.5. I have an application which allows users to register... I want to be able to allow users from that application to be logged into the second application if they have access. Also, both of these applications would be in different databases... Any suggestions? Btw this is not using webforms... 
Is it possible to apply the roles manager from that first application into the second? Or would I just need to create new roles in the second application?

What I have tried:

I have to implement a number of solutions that were on google but most seem to be using webforms... which i dont know how to use...

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure an API which will act as an Authorization Server.

The "Auth" server will issue JSON Web Tokens for authenticated users and those users will present this JWT to the protected end points (Resource Servers) in order to access them.

Your MVC web applications will act as Resource Servers.

Read [Implement JSON Web Tokens Authentication in ASP.NET Web API and and Identity 2.1](http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/)